# How to publish Codenarc report for Gradle project in Jenkins?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, gradle, codenarc

I am trying to generate Codenarc reports for my Gradle Groovy project and publish them in Jenkins.

I successfully configured my Gradle project to produce Codenarc reports with:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'codenarc'
...
dependencies {
    codenarc 'org.codenarc:CodeNarc:0.21'
    ...
}
codenarc {
    configFile = file('config/codenarc/codenarc.groovy')
    // sourceSets = [project.sourceSets.main] // run codenarc on production sources only
    ignoreFailures = true // Let the build finish even though there are code warnings
    reportFormat = 'xml'
    reportsDir = new File("build/reports/codenarc")
}
```

**config/codenarc/codenarc.groovy**

```
// Read and choose rules here: http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rule-index.html 
ruleset {
    ruleset('rulesets/basic.xml')
}
```

I also set up a job on Jenkins with the Violations plugin, but when the Violations report is generated it does not show the actual code violations. It just shows statistics, and a blank page if I press the groovy file with violations.

I have Grails projects with the Codenarc plugin, which shows up with full code snippets in the violations report, so I am guessing there is something wrong with my Codenarc setup in Gradle?

Any help or suggestions are very welcome!

Edit:
If relevant, the resulting Codenarc XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<CodeNarc url='http://www.codenarc.org' version='0.21'>
    <Report timestamp='07-10-2014 15:31:18'/>
    <Project title=''>
        <SourceDirectory>src\groovy</SourceDirectory>
    </Project>
    <PackageSummary totalFiles='124' filesWithViolations='118' priority1='0' priority2='156'
                    priority3='143'></PackageSummary>
    <Package path='testmodel' totalFiles='124' filesWithViolations='118' priority1='0' priority2='156'
             priority3='143'></Package>
    <Package path='testmodel/begivenheder' totalFiles='31' filesWithViolations='30' priority1='0' priority2='32'
             priority3='17'>
        <File name='AbstraktTest.groovy'>
            <Violation ruleName='ClassJavadoc' priority='2' lineNumber='5'>
                <SourceLine><![CDATA[@CompileStatic]]></SourceLine>
                <Message><![CDATA[Class testmodel.begivenheder.AbstraktAendring missing JavaDoc]]></Message>
            </Violation>
            ...
        </File>
    </Package>
    <Rules>
        <Rule name='AbcMetric'>
            <Description>
                <![CDATA[Checks the ABC size metric for methods/classes. A method (or "closure field") with an ABC score greater than the maxMethodAbcScore property (60) causes a violation. Likewise, a class that has an (average method) ABC score greater than the maxClassAverageMethodAbcScore property (60) causes a violation.]]></Description>
        </Rule>
        ...
    </Rules>
</CodeNarc>
```

Comment: Do You have any example project to try?

Comment: perhaps it is related to this open Jenkins issue? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17722. Symptoms seem identical.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [HTML Publisher plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)
You can configure report parameters in job configuration *Post-build Actions* or if you are using pipeline, add these lines to your Jenkinsfile:

```
node('slaveName') {

    // git, build, test, stages omitted

    stage('Publish') {

        echo 'Publish Codenarc report'
        publishHTML(
                target: [
                        allowMissing         : false,
                        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                        keepAll              : true,
                        reportDir            : 'target/site',
                        reportFiles          : 'codenarc.html',
                        reportName           : "Codenarc Report"
                ]
        )
    }

}
```